# unable to take Date dynamically every day in ssis

Tags: sql, ssis

I have created SSIS to generate a excel file from sql
and giving file name dynamically depending upon todays date.

I have not yet deployed package because of testing.

When I changed System date to test wether it is able to create file for that date or not 
but it is giving me an following error

```
Error at Data Flow Task [Excel Destination [34]]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E37.
Error at Data Flow Task [Excel Destination [34]]: Opening a rowset failed. Check that the object exists in the database.
Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: "component "Excel Destination" (34)" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".
Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: One or more component failed validation.
Error at Data Flow Task : There were errors during task validation.
 (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)
```

In `excel connection manager` i have set `property excelfilepath` in `expression` 
code is `@[User::ExcelFileName] + (DT_WSTR, 20) (DT_DBDATE) GETDATE()+".xls"`

which is giving evaluated value like `C:\2013-05-24.xls`

How do I resolved it.

Comment: Is `Goodhart` your source or destination?

Comment: It is a destination table which i'm creating to map with sql table column  inside `excel destination editor`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this issue. In the Excel connection manager properties you have to set the "**DelayValidation**" property to **TRUE**.